# report query with a specific filter

Tags: reporting, query, workbench

I need to change an picklist value that is used in many reports to filter on.  I need a way to find all reports where the filter is used so that I can also update the reports.  I am in Workbench, but cannot figure out how to query this data or if it is even possible. Please help, thanks!!

Comment: Using eclipse you can search for that field and it will show you a list of all the places the field is being used. There maybe be other ways too but I know this is one way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using MavensMate for this, as it's faster than Eclipse.

It includes simple to use Find functionality that works in the same way as Ctrl + f in Chrome or Windows to search for keywords, in your Salesforce metadata - like the picklist value in Reports. You can also replace values using this tool.

There's no need to use script to check the metadata.

[image: MavensMate Find screenshot]

To install MavensMate:

Download Sublime Text 3 [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)

Follow the Installation [instructions](http://mavensmate.com/Getting_Started/Users) and use Package Control to install MavensMate

Then create a folder for your workspace and set the path to it in the settings, in Sublime Text MavensMate>Settings>User and restart Sublime Text so that the changes take effect.

Create a new project MavensMate>Project>NewProject. This will open the project in your web browser.

Create the new project, logging into Production.

Next go to the Advanced tab, select Report and click Update Project. Then, when the message confirming that the Project has been updated appears, click Refresh Index. If you have a lot of reports in your org, this will take a while.

Next, go to the Project MetaData tab and select the report folders that you want to query, using the check boxes. Click Update Project.

Once the update is finished, you will see the Reports folder contained in your project's SRC folder, in Sublime Text.

Right click on the Reports folder and select find in folder, then enter your keyword in the Find field, this will display all reports with the keyword in their filter.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a difficult task. You can pull report xml files using eclipse or mavensmate. Then if you can write some script to parse through xml files and check for filter section in xml, you can find if the field is used.

```
<filter>
    <criteriaItems>
        <column>Object__c.Field1__c</column>
        <operator>equals</operator>
        <value>New Employer</value>
    </criteriaItems>
    <criteriaItems>
        <column>Object__c.Field2__c</column>
        <operator>equals</operator>
        <value>&lt;=90</value>
    </criteriaItems>
</filter>
```

But unless number of reports is so big, it is better to check manually instead of scripts.